# Changes just in Xcode 4 simulator visible

Tags: xcode4, ios-simulator

I found a curious problem: I added a new Button to my ViewController.xib which is visible on my simulator. But when I test it on my iPhone it doesn't appear. So far I found out that no "new" changes on my ViewController appear, although I cleaned, build my project new and deleted my app on the iPhone (no changes). Does anyone have an idea how to make it visible on the iPhone? 
Updateded:
I misspelled in my text above .Xib instead of .xib, so it is written right. Maybe I got a clue, why I get no changes on my IPhone: when I compare it with other projects, there is a "M" for modified on the right side of the overview. In my case I have just a "-" . So maybe something is wrong with the linking, what do you think?
Thank you and best regards!

Comment: Are you using any image to display on that button instead of text?

Comment: Hello! No, it is a standard Button with text (no image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File system on Device is case-sesitive. You must name your xib as ViewController.xib and follow the case exactly.

Comment: ok, so after deleeting and adding the .xib to my project again, I solved this problem. Thank you for your answers!